# How to Assign Value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 Columns based on the same table. Please refer to the below Screenshot.

[image]

I want to be assigned ReferenceNO to null values are present in ApplicationNo Column.
There is any way to assign values?
Your assistance will help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no screenshot, please attach the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you @RostamBamasi Please have look once again I pasted the IMG link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below in SQL before sending data to PowerBi  :

```
 Isnull(ApplicationNo,ReferenceNo) as ApplicationNo
```

or in Power Bi add a custom column and code like below; Help link : [Custom Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-custom-column) :

```
= if [ApplicationNo] = null then [ReferenceNo] else [ApplicationNo]
```

or add a conditional column in power bi. Help link : [Conditional Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-conditional-column).

Answer (score 0):

[@Rostam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000585/6908282) replaces `null` in `ApplicationNo` with `ReferenceNo` using DAX or SQL.

But based on what I understand, I think what you're looking for is a feature called "[Fill Down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column#fill-down)" in PowerBI. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34ZMM4vajos) for an example.

- What this doesn't is basically copies the data from the last found non-empty cell to current cell.
- You can also do the opposite using "[Fill Up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column#fill-up)"

Note: I recommend doing this because this maintains data consistency.

Comment: when we use 'fill up' or 'fill down' it replaces the same value

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But replacing it with RefNo means that you will have same data in 2 columns. Which is not very ideal for data analytics. But looks like that's your requirement.